# Is there a way to force precedence in a regex (perl style)

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

As far as I understand it, parentheses increase precedence allowing a greedy match on the right to take precedence over one on the left.

My problem is that I want to catch the remaining left hand value so I need to parenthesise that.

Is there any other way to bump the right hand side up?

example text:

```
some words      blah blah   123
```

example (wrong) regex:

```
/^([\w ]+)\s{2,}([\w ]+)\s{2,}([\w ]+)$/
```

I need \s+ to be greedier than the [\w ]+ in grabbing spaces.  I might be able to rule out multiple spaces in the word(s) match with an assertion but I'm still trying to get my head around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never try to mix overlapping classes with greedy or un-greedy quantifers.
You must know what you want and carve out distinct boundries.

```
 # /^\s*(\w(?:[ ]?\w+)*)\s{2,}(\w(?:[ ]?\w+)*)\s{2,}(\w(?:[ ]?\w+)*)\s*$/

 (?x)                     # Modifier group, x = eXpanded
 ^                        # BOL
 \s*                      # optional many whitespaces at start
 ( \w (?: [ ]? \w+ )* )   # (1) word char start, word char end, optional 1 space between words
 \s{2,}                   # minimum 2 whitespace
 ( \w (?: [ ]? \w+ )* )   # (2) word char start, word char end, optional 1 space between words
 \s{2,}                   # minimum 2 whitespace
 ( \w (?: [ ]? \w+ )* )   # (3) word char start, word char end, optional 1 space between words
 \s*                      # optional many witespaces before end
 $                        # EOL
```

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is incorrect. Parentheses don't increase precedence, simply do grouping. The problem is that quantifiers advance as much as they can so `([\w ]+)` matches until last two whitespace characters. Your example is not very clear but you can use non-greedy quantifiers adding an extra `?`.

Here a test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
        m/^([\w ]+?)\s{2,}([\w ]+?)\s{2,}([\w ]+?)$/;
        print "$1 -- $2 -- $3\n";
}

__DATA__
some words      blah blah   123
```

That yields:

```
some words -- blah blah -- 123
```

Comment: Regarding the precedence, I took reference from http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch08_05.htm